# 'Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command Error when trying do run python commands

Tags: python, pip, path

I am trying to run a python file and I get the error: 'Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I know there have been questions like this one before but even after reading the answers, I was not able to resolve this issue. I have included a screenshot of my environment variables, but it already has `C:\Python34\Scripts`. I have also tried modifying the python file to include PATH, but nothing changed. When I manually look for the Python 3.10 file, I find the file path `C:\Users\faiqf\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.10`. I'm not sure if it has been installed in the wrong place. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Result of `echo %PATH%` are
`C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\faiqf\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\faiqf\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\faiqf\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Python34\Scripts;`

Comment: `C:\Python34\Scripts` doesn't contain `python.exe`.  `C:\Python34` would be the correct location.  Alternatively, IIRC Python 3.4 comes with PyLauncher and it is in `c:\windows`.  Try `py` instead of `Python`.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what I need to do to fix the problem. When I just search `python` in the command prompt, I still get the same error. Also, I can't find `C:\Python34`.

Comment: did you try `py`?  If you can't find `c:\python34` then even `c:\python34\scripts` is wrong.  `py` (the [PyLauncher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=pylauncher#python-launcher-for-windows), if installed) will detect all registered Pythons in the system and run the latest one.

Comment: When I type `py` I get `Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.` But, I am trying to use pip and I still can't.

Comment: `py -m pip install <whatever>`, but realize Python 3.10 was just released and many 3rd party modules don't support it yet.  If just learning, stick to Python 3.9 for a few months until the modules catch up.  `py -0` will also list available other Python versions if you have multiple installed.  `py -X.Y` where X.Y is the python version will run a specific version.

Comment: `py -m pip install` worked. Thanks a lot! Whenever I need to use pip, will I have to use this instead?

Comment: Yes, if you use the PyLauncher, which I recommend anyway.  You can have multiple Pythons installed and `py -x.y -m pip` will install modules in the particular x.y version specified.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable shortcut setting under the "Manage App Execution Aliases"

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong path location for python 3.10. By default, Python 3.10 is installed in this folder `C:\Users\Username\AppData\lacal\Programs\Python\Python310\` on windows.
Add the following to your env path `C:\Users\faiqf\AppData\lacal\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts`,
then close your command line and open another one.
You can now use `python` or `py`.

Answer (score 0):

The path that worked for me was
`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`. `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.10` doesn't work because it's a path for the **shortcut** of the python file. You need to right-click the shortcut, click **Properties**, then copy and paste the path at **Start in** into your Path environment variable.